# Program for Date calculator in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a date calculator in C program with the range from 1/1/1902 to 12/31/2299, I've follow the algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week  with the century table,month table and day table, but when I tried to print out, this is what I have

```
Enter Year, Month and Day as YYYY,M,DD
1982 4 24
Saturday1982 ,6, 24, is  6
```

Instead of saying `1982 4 24 is a Saturday`

What is wrong in the program I wrote? The placement of the switch cases?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    // insert code here...
    int day,month,year;

    printf("Enter Year, Month and Day as YYYY,M,DD\n");

    scanf("%4d%d%2d", &year, &month, &day);

    if (year >= 1901 && year <= 2299 &&
        month >= 1 && month <= 12 &&
        day >= 0 && day <= 31)
    {
        int century = year/100;

        /* making a century table for calculation*/

        switch(century)
        {
            case 19:
                century=0;
                break;
            case 20:
                century=6;
                break;
            case 21:
                century=4;
                break;
            case 22:
                century=2;
                break;
        }

        int last2_of_year= year % 100;

        /* Last 2 digits of the year entered*/

        int last2_div_4 =  last2_of_year/4;

        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                month=0;
                break;

            case 2:
                month=3;
                break;
            case 3:
                month=3;
                break;
            case 4:
                month=6;
                break;
            case 5:
                month=1;
                break;
            case 6:
                month=4;
                break;
            case 7:
                month=6;
                break;
            case 8:
                month=2;
                break;
            case 9:
                month=5;
                break;
            case 10:
                month=0;
                break;
            case 11:
                month=3;
                break;
            case 12:
                month=5;
                break;
         }


        int total_num = (century+ last2_of_year +day +month +last2_div_4)%7;

        switch (total_num) 
        {
            case 0:
            printf("Sunday");
                break;
            case 1:
            printf("Monday");
                break;
            case 2:
            printf("Tuesday");
                break;
            case 3:
            printf("Wednesday");
                break;
            case 4:
            printf("Thursday");
                break;
            case 5:
            printf("Friday");
                break;
            case 6:
            printf("Saturday");
                break;
        }

        printf("%d ,%d, %d, is a %d", year,month,day,total_num);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("invalid\n");
        }



    return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like @QuantumMechanic found the root cause of the problem, but I'd like to suggest a few changes:

```
    int century = year/100;

    /* making a century table for calculation*/

    switch(century)
    {
        case 19:
            century=0;
            break;
```

I'm *very* leery of using a single variable to represent two different things. Here, `century` represents both the user-input human-readable century *and* an offset to the first day of the week for the century. Two variables would give clearer code, and allow you to re-use the `century` information later, should the need arise.

Second, using a `case` statement to store offsets for the months feels a little ... overdone:

```
    switch (month)
    {
        case 1:
            month=0;
            break;

        case 2:
            month=3;
            break;
        case 3:
            month=3;
            break;
```

This could instead be handled with an array lookup:

```
int leap_month[] = [-1, 6, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5];
int norm_month[] = [-1, 0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5];

if (leap_year)
    month_offset = leap_month[month];
else
    month_offset = norm_month[month];
```

The `-1` is just to allow referring to the table with human-friendly indexes (`Jan == 1`). Feel free to remove it and use `leap_month[month-1]` or similar if you find that easier.

Comment: @Tuan, heh, the strange things teachers will force students to do when learning to program...

Answer (score 2):

You say:

```
printf("%d ,%d, %d, is a %d", year,month,day,total_num);
```

That's going to print

```
L, M, N, is a P
```

where `L`, `M`, `N`, and `P` are numbers.

You need that `printf()` **before** the name-of-days `switch` and need to remove the final `%d` and the `total_num` from the `printf`.  Then that `printf` will print

```
L, M, N, is a
```

and the `printf`s in the name-of-days `switch` will print out the name of the day on the same line, giving you

```
L, M, N, is a XXXXXXXXXXX
```

---

**Edited to address comment:**

Look at your program for output statements.

The first output statement encountered are the `printf` calls in the name-of-days switch that prints out the day names.  So when your program runs given the input you mention, the first thing that will be printed out is

```
Saturday
```

Then after the name-of-days switch the next `printf` is

```
printf("%d ,%d, %d, is a %d", year,month,day,total_num);
```

Since `year` is `1982`, `month` is `4`, `day` is `24`, and `total_num` is `6`, that `printf` will output

```
1982, 4, 24, is a 6
```

on the same line as the previous `Saturday` output, which means the entire output is

```
Saturday1982, 4, 24, is a 6
```

Comment: Ok I did what you told me...but some how my month print a different number, a number from my switch case, please look at the output

Enter Year, Month and Day as YYYY,M,DD 
Running…
1982 4 24
1982 ,6, 24, is a 6Saturday

I changed my 4 to a 6, did I do the switch case wrong?

Comment: @Tuan Nguyen - you are changing it in your switch(month) case. I.E. case 4:
                month=6;
                break;

Comment: so it should be case 4: 6=month; ? Instead? I tried that but it gave me lvalues error

Comment: No.  There's nothing wrong with the switch.  The problem is the location and contents of the `printf`.  It needs to be **before** the Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/etc. switch and it needs the final format string and final parameter removed.

Comment: You seem to be using the result of the case in your total_num calculation.  Just use another variable.  E.g. tempMonth = month before the month switch.  Use tempMonth in the total_num calculation and it should print out the original value of month.

Comment: Or what QuantumMechanic suggests.  That's easier since it kills both bugs in one shot.

Comment: @Duck, so should you suggest I should do something like int tempMonth=month; right before the month switch case?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic this is what I did following your suggestion, here is my code


   int total_num = (century+ last2_of_year +day +month +last2_div_4)%7;
  
  
   printf("%d, %d, %d, is a  ", year, month, day);
   
   switch (total_num) 
   {
   case 0:
   printf("Sunday");
    break;
   case 1:
   printf("Monday");
    break;
   case 2:
   printf("Tuesday");
    break;
   case 3:
   printf("Wednesday");
    break;
   case 4:
   printf("Thursday");
    break;
   case 5:
   printf("Friday");
    break;
   case 6:
   printf("Saturday");
    break;
   }

Comment: I think, if you are going to further expand this pgm, you should do things along the lines of what sarnold and I suggest.  If you are done with this pgm after this is resolved then moving the printf is fine.  It will work.